# How do I nest widgets in kendoui using PHP wrapper?

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, treeview, kendo-ui

I wrote a code so as in manual with treeview.

```
div id="treview-back">
<?php

$treeview = new \Kendo\UI\TreeView('treeview');

// helper function that creates TreeViewItem with imageUrl
function ImageTreeViewItem($text) {
    $item = new \Kendo\UI\TreeViewItem($text);
    return $item;
}

$msg = ImageTreeViewItem('Message');
$msg->addItem(
            ImageTreeViewItem('New Message'),
            ImageTreeViewItem('Replay')
        );    
$msg->expanded(true);
$inbox = ImageTreeViewItem('Home');
$inbox->expanded(TRUE);
$inbox->addItem($msg);

$dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\HierarchicalDataSource();

// add root-level nodes as datasource data
$dataSource->data(array($inbox));
$treeview->dataSource($dataSource);

echo $treeview->render();
?></div>
```

I need to add a Splitter widget, how do I have to do it? I didn't find it at manual.
Why, if I add this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: true
 });</script>
```

The TreeView disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the code is pretty much the same that you were doing for a `tree`.

```
<div id="outer-splitter">
    <?php
    $treeview = new \Kendo\UI\TreeView('treeview');

    // helper function that creates TreeViewItem with imageUrl
    function ImageTreeViewItem($text) {
        $item = new \Kendo\UI\TreeViewItem($text);
        return $item;
    }

    $msg = ImageTreeViewItem('Message');
    $msg->addItem(ImageTreeViewItem('New Message'), ImageTreeViewItem('Replay'));
    $msg->expanded(true);
    $inbox = ImageTreeViewItem('Home');
    $inbox->expanded(TRUE);
    $inbox->addItem($msg);

    $dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\HierarchicalDataSource();

    // add root-level nodes as datasource data
    $dataSource->data(array($inbox));
    $treeview->dataSource($dataSource);

    // Create Left Pane
    $leftPane = new \Kendo\UI\SplitterPane();
    $leftPane->attr("id", "left-pane")->collapsible(true)->size(220)->content($treeview->render());

    // Create Right Pane
    $rightPane = new \Kendo\UI\SplitterPane();
    $rightPane->attr("id", "right-pane")->collapsible(true)->size(220)->startContent();
    ?>

    <div>
        Right pane
    </div>


    <?php
    $rightPane->endContent();

    // create outer splitter
    $splitter = new \Kendo\UI\Splitter('splitter');
    $splitter->orientation("horizontal");
    $splitter->addPane($leftPane);
    $splitter->addPane($rightPane);

    echo $splitter->render();
    ?>
</div>
```

You need to use `\Kendo\UI\Splitter` for configuring the `Splitter, setting its`content`. Here I used:

- `orientation` for setting the orientation of the pane. `horizontal` means that they are tiled horizontally.
- `addPane` Allows you to add `\Kendo\Ui\SplitterPane`.
- In `\Kendo\Ui\SplitterPane`, I've used `content` for adding the another widget definition inside and `startContent` and `endContent` for delimiting the begin and end of an HTML block.

You can find very good information in [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/php/widgets/splitter/overview).

Your code makes the splitter disappear since that's a different way of using Kendo UI widgets (pure-JavaScript, not using PHP wrappers) and in that piece of code you are not defining the content of the *new* TreeView.